# variable substitution in helm values file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm deploying a chart where I can add freely-defined key-value pairs( the [sonarqube helm chart](https://github.com/SonarSource/helm-chart-sonarqube/blob/cd6335cac29ed81a584fb97685f7441ee823bfc2/charts/sonarqube/values.yaml#L345) specifically but that's not relevant I think).

My values file looks like this:

```
...
sonar.properties:
  ldap.user: "myuser"   
  ldap.password: "mypassword"  
...
```

Now, I don't want to write the password on the values file, but neither can I pass it directly to helm with `--set ldap.password=mypassword` , since it's not a parameter of the chart, and I really don't want to modify the chart.

The question is: Is there a way to have variable replacement on the values file itself?

I saw the `helm --post-renderer` flag but I feel like this problem is generic enough to have a simpler solution instead of `sed/awk`-ing around, maybe I missed something in the docs.

Comment: You can only do this if the chart uses the `tpl` function to re-render variables, so if the chart isn't one you control, that's not an option.  You may look at higher-level tools like [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile) that have similar capabilities.